# Crypto JS: Can you slow down decryption, without an exponential file size increase?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs, brute-force

I have the following:

```
let original = 'something'
let passphrase = uuidv4()

// will take place on the server
let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(original, passphrase)

// will take place on the browser
// I want this part to take  ≈ 10 minutes *minimum*
let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, passphrase)
```

I tried an iterative approach. Controlling the decrypting iterations needed means you can also control the decryption time to some degree:

```
// increase this until we reach the desired decryption time on the browser
let numberOfEncryptions = 2

// will take place on the server
let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(original, passphrase).toString()

let i = 0

while (i < numberOfEncryptions) {
  encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(encrypted, passphrase).toString()
  i++
}


// will take place on the browser:

let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, passphrase).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)

i = 0

while (i < numberOfEncryptions) {
  decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decrypted, passphrase).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
  i++
}

await checkWithServer(decrypted) // returns true
```

The results were disappointing.

Increasing the number of encryptions on the server also increases the time of decryption on the browser which is great because this is what I want.

But it also increases the size of the encrypted file exponentially which is horrible as the user cannot possibly download such a huge file in order to the decrypt it.

Is there some other solution?

**UPDATE:**

@SlavaKnyazev suggested I should instead encrypt the passphrase used to encrypt the data and send a **hint** to the end-user for them to brute-force for the passphrase.

Instead of spending time decrypting the data itself the user will spend time brute-forcing for the passphrase.

This is how I tried to implement this (as a test):

```
  const KEY = 'ab' // uuidv4()
  const dataToEncrypt = 'The Message'
  const md5key = CryptoJS.MD5(KEY).toString()
  const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(dataToEncrypt, md5key)

  const sha1keyHint = CryptoJS.SHA1(KEY).toString()

  let pool = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('')
  let before = Date.now()
  let after
  let md5keyFromHint

  bruteForce(pool, (value) => {
    if(CryptoJS.SHA1(value).toString() === sha1keyHint) {
      md5keyFromHint = CryptoJS.MD5(value).toString()
      after = Date.now()
      console.log(`KEY is ${value}`)
      console.log(`Found after ${(after - before) / 1000} seconds`)
      return true
    }
    return false
  })

  const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, md5keyFromHint).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
  console.log(dataToEncrypt === decrypted) // returns true
```

I turns out `KEY` has to be rather "simple" and not a `uuidv4()` as I thought initially. Otherwise, it could take forever. Also, the brute)forcing method I'm using needs a "pool" of characters to look into, I guess the bigger the pool, the longer it will take.

Once again my problem is that the user will not be spending time decrypting the actual data. So it feels like PoW, i.e. faking it.

But I'll consider the question answered this time and will stop here. :-)

My initial goal apparently it not possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on __why__ you need this? There may be better ways.

Comment: I guess you hadn't taken [Rani's advice from the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66942890/can-i-force-the-decryption-of-some-data-on-the-browser-to-take-time#comment118331301_66942890) to heart: *"Don't provide the user with the full decryption passphrase. Give only a partial key and make them guess/search for the rest of the key."*

Comment: I did but the requirement handed to me now is this minimum-time limit. How do I control that, regardless of what type of data I ask the user to decrypt? Hopefully this the format of this post is clearer and not a mere duplicate :)

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I updated with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give the key, give a hash of the key. The length of the key to brute-force will give you the granularity you're looking for.

Encryption process:

1. Generate a key (ex: hunter2) and encrypt your data using it.
2. Hash hunter2 using an algorithm such as SHA1 (f3bbbd66a63d4bf1747940578ec3d0103530e21d)
3. Make the client brute-force it for the key

The longer the key, the exponentially longer it will take to find it, while the size of the payload remains constant.

This has a flaw however -- brute-forcing is not necessary, as brute-forcing the AES encryption will be just as straight forward. This can be defeated by salting by making the key a hash as well.

Encrypt your data using not "hunter2", but using `MD5(hunter2)` (use a different algorithm).

Throw in some salt to the hashes to prevent the effective usage of rainbow tables.

Pseudo code:

```
// Encrypt
let key = "password";
let aesKey = md5(password);
let hint = sha1(password);

let encryptedData = data.encrypt(aesKey);

let decryptedData = data.decrypt(md5(bruteForceSha1(hint));
```

Comment: Could you provide me with a short example (in Javascript) if possible where the key handed to the user is then brute-forced (with some method) and the time it takes for the brute-forcing to finish is around 10-20' on an average browser/machine. If it's too much I will accept your answer regardless :-) (I will not ask again on a different OP - and sorry for the noise)

Comment: My CryptoJs knowledge is very limited

Comment: How do I "Throw in some salt to the hashes" ? Also is there a good Js brute-forcing module to use to test this ? :)

Comment: Salting a hash means adding a constant to the value. This is because the hash value of hunter2 is well-known and can be looked up in databases. The hash value of "hunter2sfsavvgdarfsaf" is not.

Comment: I was thinking that my initial key/passphrase (your `let key = "password"` in your example) could actually be `let key = uuidv4()`. Do I still need salt in this case ?

Comment: Also, when you brute-force for something you need to check each time round the loop whether you've found the key or not. How is the client going to check each time around every brute-forcing loop ? Make a request to the server  every time? That's a lot of requests? The idea was for the decryption to take place on the browser without any server communication before it's done otherwise the performance would be really bad. Unless I'm still missing the idea behind the brute-forcing solution

Comment: I have updated the OP with my concerns :-/

Comment: Updated the OP one last time. I think now I get what you meant.

Comment: The hashes get bruteforced locally, there’s no need to make any requests.